# I'm trying to find sum of first n palindromes using python

Tags: python, while-loop, palindrome

Here's my code:

```
def ispalindrome(p):
    temp = p
    rev = 0
    while temp != 0:
        rev = (rev * 10) + (temp % 10)
        temp = temp // 10
    if num == rev:
        return True
    else:
        return False

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
i = 1
count = 0
sum = 0
while (count <= num - 1):
    if (palindrome(i) == True):
        sum = sum + i
        count = count + 1
    i = i + 1
print("Sum of first", num, "palindromes is", sum)
```

I believe my ispalindrome() function works. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong inside my while loop.
here's my output so far:

n = 1 answer = 1,

n = 2 answer = 22,

n = 3 answer = 333 ...

I also think the runtime on this really sucks
Please help

Comment: welcome, replace ```palindrome``` with ```ispalindrome```

Comment: I just did, it still doesn't work

Comment: In `if num == rev: return True` `num` is the variable `num = int(input("Enter a number: "))` from _global_ scope. Are you sure you intended to compare with `num`, and not `p`, for example?

Comment: Ah right, yeah I meant to compare it with p
Thank you @ForceBru

Comment: To check if it is a palindrome, it's easier to reverse is as a string. Your function can be replaced with return str(p) == str(p)[::-1]

Comment: @StefvanderZon Wow, that definitely is a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

i belive the problem is with your `ispalindrom` functon it returns 200 as  palindrome number

```
def ispalindrome(p):
    rev = int(str(p)[::-1])
    if p == rev:
        return True
    else:
        return False

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
i = 1
count = 0
sum = 0
while (count <= num - 1):
    if (ispalindrome(i) == True):
        print(i)
        sum = sum + i
        count = count + 1
    i = i + 1
print("Sum of first", num, "palindromes is", sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_palindrome(number):
    return str(number) == str(number)[::-1]

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
palindromes = [i for i in range(1, num) if is_palindrome(i)]
print(f"Sum of the {len(palindromes)} palindromes in range {num} is {sum(palindromes)}")
```